# explain me a preg_match if clause please

Tags: php, preg-match

```
        if(preg_match("/^[\w_.]+$/",stripslashes($_GET['key']))) {
        $key = $wpdb->escape(stripslashes($_GET['key']));
    }
```

assuming the key value is = be4e53680e6518cca701ec091258642f0740fe3d

can someone please explain me the if condition ? I`m confused on what exactly it checks for

ok thanks guys for the clarification on that.
now i`m posting one more line of code that ties with this one. if u can help me understand it.

```
        if(preg_match("/^[\w_.]+$/",stripslashes($_GET['key']))) {
        $key = $wpdb->escape(stripslashes($_GET['key']));
    } else {
        if(preg_match("/^[\w_.]+$/",$name)) {
            $wpdb->query("some query;");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

assuming $_GET['key'] = be4e53680e6518cca701ec091258642f0740fe3d

$name = TomJones

what i got so far is:
If $_GET['key'] is numeric then $key = stripslashes (get_key)

but when does the else kiks in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks for strings containing alphanumeric characters, underscores and dots in the key param from request, underscore is ommitable because \w handles it

Comment: Dot shouldn't be escaped because it's in a character class. See this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX7xQ9)

Comment: posted a edit to my code..pls check

Comment: when the key param does not meet the regexp, mostly when it will be empty or does not contain any of the characters metioned above